# WildFly plugin for Gradle

Tags: gradle, wildfly, wildfly-8

Is there a plugin available for Gradle that can be used for deploying to a remote WildFly server? I did a search and couldn't find anything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WildFly team is aware of this and working on it. I'll keep you update on when the plugin would be available. In the meanwhile, you can look at the Maven plugin at:

https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/

Answer (score 3):

You can already utilize the [Cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) for this. It supports deploying to a remote WildFly server.

Comment: I get this error: `Execution failed for task ':cargoRunLocal'. Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [wildfly10x], type = [installed]], configuration type [standalone]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it?`

Comment: @kiltek: Your question has been answered on the [GitHub page for the Cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin/issues/152).

Comment: I added these lines to my `build.gradle` file, but I still get the same error: `def cargoVersion = '1.4.5'
 cargo "org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-uberjar:$cargoVersion",
 "org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-ant:$cargoVersion"`

Comment: Please don't double post your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle plugin is already available at:
https://github.com/nikit-cpp/wildflyDeployPlugin